# wordpress is converting ?page=2 into /2

Tags: pagination

with this code

```
paginate_links( 
  array(
   'base' => @add_query_arg('page', '%#%'), 
   'format' => '?page=%#%&a='.$a, 
   )
)
```

looks output like this

```
<a class="page-numbers" href="/wordpress/something/?page=2;a=1">2</a>
```

But when I click on it my url goes to `www.example.com/something/2/?a=1` is it possible to change it into  `www.example.com/something/?page=2&a=1`?

Thanks

Comment: why would you want that?

Comment: because I'm showing custom data from custom table

Comment: That is not an explanation to why you need page to be set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You can disable redirection by category name or page name or whatever you choose.

```
function wpren_disable_redirect( $query ) {

    if( 'uncategorized' == $query->query_vars['category_name'] ) 
        remove_filter( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );

}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'wpren_disable_redirect' );
```